# How to achieve SUM using UNION operation

Tags: sql, database, database-administration, hana

I want to perform SUM with UNION operation. But there is an error.

```
SELECT x.YEAR_WISE,x.OFFICE_NAME,x.CATEGORY,x.KWT_COUNT,x.NON_KWT_COUNT FROM x
UNION ALL
SELECT ''AS YEAR_WISE,'' AS OFFICE_NAME,'SUM',sum(x.KWT_COUNT),sum(x.NON_KWT_COUNT)FROM x;
```

Here x is created using WITH command [with x as(select * from ..)]

The output in x is as follows:

```
YEAR_WISE    OFFICE_NAME                 CATEGORY   KWT_COUNT   NON_KWT_COUNT
 2,019    HeadQuarters-MultiSpeciality   Doctor        18          40
 2,019    HeadQuarters-MultiSpeciality   Nurse          7          16
```

On performing UNION and SUM the output that is required is as follows:

```
YEAR_WISE    OFFICE_NAME                 CATEGORY   KWT_COUNT   NON_KWT_COUNT
 2,019    HeadQuarters-MultiSpeciality   Doctor        18          40
 2,019    HeadQuarters-MultiSpeciality   Nurse          7          16
                                         SUM           25          56
```

How to achieve this output? What is the modification required in query?

Note that I don't want subquery, I want TOTAL SUM at bottom.

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: Based on the belwo sql error query

SELECT x.YEAR_WISE,x.OFFICE_NAME,x.CATEGORY,x.KWT_COUNT,x.NON_KWT_COUNT FROM x
UNION ALL
SELECT ''AS YEAR_WISE,'' AS OFFICE_NAME,'SUM' AS CATEGORY,sum(x.KWT_COUNT),sum(x.NON_KWT_COUNT)
FROM x
GROUP BY 
  x.YEAR_WISE,
     x.OFFICE_NAME,
    x.CATEGORY;

I am getting 

SQL Error [339] [HY000]: SAP DBTech JDBC: [339]: invalid number: not a valid number string ''

Comment: SQL Error [339] [HY000]: SAP DBTech JDBC: [339]: invalid number: not a valid number string ''

Comment: I would convert `year_wise` to string (in first part of union) or replace `SELECT '' AS YEAR_WISE,` with `SELECT null AS YEAR_WISE,` - I don't know about particular DBMS however.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT x.YEAR_WISE
      ,x.OFFICE_NAME
      ,x.CATEGORY
      ,sum(x.KWT_COUNT)
      ,sum(x.NON_KWT_COUNT)
FROM x
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS 
(
    (x.YEAR_WISE,x.OFFICE_NAME,x.CATEGORY)
   ,()
)
```

you can find more info about grouping sets [here](https://help.sap.com/docs/HANA_SERVICE_CF/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/d22eb360d2951014b6f0b9f1e84edce9.html).

Comment: YES ITS WORKING....THANK U.... but is there any possibility to include the word 'SUM'...let me try the date to string method and check

Comment: Yes, it should be possible with using ISNULL and converting the column to text. Let me know if you have any problems.